# Find the solution of Initial value problem in explicit form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Problem:$$
sin(2x)dx+cos(6y)dy = 0
$$
Initial value:
$$
y(\frac{π}{2})=\frac{π}{6}
$$

Integrate both sides:
$$
\frac16sin(6x)= \frac12cos(2x)+c
$$
$$
sin(6y)= 3cos(2x)+c
$$
Use initial condition to find: c=3
$$
sin(6y)=3cos(2x)+3
$$
Use trig IDs
$$
sin(6y)=6cos^2(x)
$$
Solve for y
$$
y=\frac16sin^{-1}(6cos^2(x))
$$
Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Does it satisfy the differential equation? Does it go through the point you need it to?

Comment: I dont know could you help

Comment: Plug the solution you found into the equation to see if it satisfies. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\sin2x\ dx+\cos 6y\ dy=0,\ \ y\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$

$$\cos6y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\sin2x$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac16\sin6y\right)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(\cos^2x)$$Integrate both sides with respect to $x$
$$\dfrac16\sin6y=\cos^2x+C$$$$\sin6y=6\cos^2x+C$$
We just obtained an implicit formula for the general solution. To determine $C$ set $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $y=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$$\sin\pi=6\cos^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)+C$$$$0=0+C$$$$C+0$$
Hence the solution of the initial value problem is given implicitly by $$\sin6y=6\cos^2x$$To solve for y we must exercise a little caution. The answer $y(x)=\dfrac16\arcsin(6\cos^2x)$ is wrong because then $y(\pi/2)=0$, not $\pi/6$

To match $y(\pi/2)=\pi/6$ we must choose $y=\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac16\arcsin(6\cos^2x)$.